# Exporting the stack traces from an Xcode Instruments Allocation trace

Tags: ios, xcode, instruments

I'm using XCode/Instruments to trace allocations on an iOS app. I can select a region of the trace and view the persistent items, as well as seeing the stack trace where it was allocated.

Is there anyway I can export the stack trace of all these items in the range?  I wish to collate the information and figure out where is the most common entry point, or just search for key entry points.

Comment: Any updates? Same needs here.